# Plotly sliders update on mouse release / click

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Using Plotly in Python, how do I make my transitions happen only on mouse release when using sliders?

Here’s how I define my slider:

```
sliders = [
    {
        'yanchor': 'top',
        'xanchor': 'left', 
        'currentvalue': {'font': {'size': 16}, 'prefix': 'Frame: ', 'visible': False, 'xanchor': 'right'},
        'transition': {'duration': 0.0, 'easing': 'linear'},
        'pad': {'b': 10, 't': 10}, 
        'len': 0.9, 'x': 0.1, 'y': 0, 
        'steps': [{'args': [None, {'frame': {'duration': 0.0, 'easing': 'linear', 'redraw': False},
                                  'transition': {'duration': 0, 'easing': 'linear'}}], 
                   'label': k, 'method': 'animate'} for k in range(n_frames)]
    }
]

fig['layout'].update(sliders=sliders)
```

Here’s how it is behaving (updates every step when dragging the slider):
[image]

I would like the frames to update only when I release the mouse or do a click in a specific location of the slider ruler.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for here does not seem to be possible unless you're willing to make the leap to [plotly-dash](/questions/tagged/plotly-dash). And you should. It's fantastic. And if you do, you can use a [dcc.Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeGtC.png) that has a functionality that should fit your needs. And if you're by any chance using JupyterLab, you can show your figures as an app directly in your notebbok.

Unlike the slider available in your `fig`, following slider will have the "drop-then-calculate" functionality you're looking for. It won't show in the screenshot, but that setup will show a hand icon upon hovering instead of an arrow like in your example.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I’m working with dash, but the only solution I found for smooth transitions, with play and pause options, was using update menus and frames directly on plotly (which I later use inside a dcc.Graph). An advantage I think is that the animation happens entirely on the frontend, while with Dash slider there would be some delay due to the backend response.
Do you suggest any reference showing how to do exactly that with Dash components?